# Fancybox 2 ? load ajax

Tags: jquery, fancybox

My code is ,

```
$("#mySuperForm").bind("submit", function() {

            if ($("#heightimage").val().length < 1  && $("#widthimage").val().length < 1 ) {
                $("#errorimage").show('slow');
                $.fancybox.resize();
                return false;
                    }

            $.fancybox.showActivity();

            $.ajax({
                type            : "POST",
                cache   : false,
                url     : "<?php echo $lb_path;?>code.php",
                data            : $(this).serializeArray(),
                success    : function(data) {
                    setTimeout('$("#fancybox-close").trigger(\'click\')', 1000);
                    $.fancybox(data);
                    $('.insertdata fancybox.ajax').fancybox().trigger('click');

                }
            });

            return false;
        });
```

and in the code.php is

```
<input type=\"hidden\" class='insertdata ' onClick=\"insert('".$output."', '', '".$iddata."')\" />
```

but the code is not doing this in fancbox 1.34 isit ok !

sorry for bad english

Comment: add an alert before  '$.fancybox(data);' to test if all code before works

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function(){$("#fancybox-close").trigger('click')}, 1000);
```